# How to match statuscode with an Int in Scala

Tags: scala, akka-http

What would be a good way in Scala to match an integer with [Status codes defined in Akka-http](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/model/StatusCode.scala#L111):

I would like to do something like:

```
if (passedErrorCodeToMethod == 200) {
       complete(ToResponseMarshallable(StatusCodes.OK -> errorResponse))
}
else if (passedErrorCodeToMethod == 400) {
       complete(ToResponseMarshallable(StatusCodes.BadRequest -> errorResponse))     
}
```

But I obviously don't want to do this for all error codes and would rather like to have this be done via pattern matching or in a more scalable way

Comment: One quick thought is you could make a `Map[Int, Function]` where the function is the part you have in the `complete` call. Then, you just look up the response code in the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StatusCodes.getForKey(passedErrorCodeToMethod) match {
  case Some(status) => complete(status -> errorResponse)
  case None => oopsie()
}
```

Something like this ?